# Align a label with textarea

Tags: javafx, label, textarea, javafx-2, gridpane

How can I align the position of my "Description" label such that it corresponds in line with the "Enter description" text ([Label - TextArea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdhBS.png)). These components are inside an gridPane and coded in javaFX ( so no Scene Builder tips can help me here ).
Code:

```
Label descriptionLabel = new Label("Description:");
descriptionLabel.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
JFXTextArea descriptionTextArea = new JFXTextArea();
descriptionTextArea.setPadding(new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0));
descriptionTextArea.setPromptText("Enter description...");
gridPane.add(descriptionLabel, 0, 2);
gridPane.add(descriptionTextArea, 1, 2);
```

I've tried with `descriptionLabel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);` but neither that helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `GridPane` Constraints. `Valignment` set to `Top` and `Halignment` set to `Right`. [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

```
GridPane.setHalignment(descriptionLabel, HPos.RIGHT);
GridPane.setValignment(descriptionLabel, VPos.TOP);
```

**After looking at you picture again, I think you only need `setValignment`.**